# Converting a string to base64

Tags: base64

I'm trying to understand how Base64 works.
If you wanted to send `!"#` using Base64, what would it look like?

Here's my working out:

```
String: !        "        #
Hex:    21       22       23
Binary: 00100001 00100010 00100011

Base64 conversion:    
Hex:    4      12     8      23
Binary: 001000 010010 001000 100011
```

None of the final binary values are able to be represented using any of the ascii chars in Base64.

I've obviously misunderstood something here, if anyone can point me in the right direction with an example that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are using trying to re-interpret the Base64 values as characters using an ASCII table (i.e. 0x04 would be EOT). However, you will have to use the [base64 index table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table) to convert the resulting numbers back to characters (note that the index values are in decimal, not in HEX there).
Here, your values will be

```
Base64:
Hex:     4 12  8 23
String:  E  S  I  j
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: That makes sense. But from an efficiency perspective, how does Base64 help? I still need to send 24bits either way.

Comment: Actually, base64 does not help for efficiency at all. It is intended to ensure, that transmitted content can be represented in as many code pages as possible without the risk of loss or modification (e.g. by some component that interprets special characters in a surprising way). This is why, base64 encoded payload is always larger than without the encoding.